# Replacing an element in an array with a for loop javascript not properly replacing element

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a function here that replaces the elements that are multiples of 3 & 5 with "Fizz" and "Buzz" respectively. I ran the function and it only replaces the 1st element with "Fizz", and nothing else. I'm not sure why it only replaces the 1st element, since it doesn't match any of the if else statements that I have. I don't believe that I need to have the array within the function, do I, since it would mean that the array was being created while I was attempting to replace the elements.

```
var listOfNumbers = new Array(100);

var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.length; i++){
    listOfNumbers[i] = i + 1;
}

function fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers){                
    for (j = 0; j < listOfNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (j % 3 == 0 && j % 5 == 0){
            listOfNumbers[j] = "FizzBuzz";
        }
        else if (j % 3 == 0) {
            listOfNumbers[j] = "Fizz";
        }
        else if (j % 5 == 0) {
            listOfNumbers[j] = "Buzz";
        }
        else {
            listOfNumbers[j] = j;
        }
        return listOfNumbers;
    }
    document.getElementById("Nums").innerHTML = fizzBuzz();
}
```

[Array in the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6YxV.png)

I'm not sure

Also, I have a button to display the array, but it doesn't seem to display the array when clicking on it.

```
<h4>Fizz Buzz</h4>
<p>An idea that prints the elements of an array from 1 to 100, but it prints "Fizz" for every multiple of 3, "Buzz" for ever multiple of 5, and finally "FizzBuzz" for every multple of 15.
    Idea taken from <a href="https://github.com/karan/Projects#text">here</a>.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="fizzBuzz()">Click to see the results</button>
    <p id="Nums"></p>
```

Comment: why a `return` in the `for` loop?

Comment: you are `return`ing inside the for loop, thus it exits after the first iteration, and doesn't apply to the entire array.

Comment: You are not passing array to `fizzBuzz` function

Comment: Isn't the classic FizzBuzz supposed to replace multiples of 15 with `"FizzBuzz"`?

Comment: maybe you check why you change the value of the array with this line `listOfNumbers[j] = j;` it makes an assumption which is not clear, because you have already values in it, but you change it later to a different value.

Comment: That return statement was a mistake.

Comment: @Igor I forgot about the multiples of 15, I added it to the code.

Comment: Check out my code for a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

- to hand over the array,
- to check the value of the array, not the index, because it is shifted by one,
- to check for **FizzBuzz** first, to get number who are divisable by `3` and `5`,
- to return the array at the end,
- additionally declare a local variable `j`.

```js
function getFizzBuzz() {
    var listOfNumbers = new Array(100),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.length; i++) {
        listOfNumbers[i] = i + 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("Nums").innerHTML = fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers);
}

function fizzBuzz(array) {
    var j;

    for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[j] % 3 == 0 && array[j] % 5 == 0) {
            array[j] = "FizzBuzz";
        } else if (array[j] % 3 == 0) {
            array[j] = "Fizz";
        } else if (array[j] % 5 == 0) {
            array[j] = "Buzz";
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getFizzBuzz()">FizzBuzz!!!</button><br><div id="Nums"></div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I still cannot get it to show up on the webpage.

Comment: which part does not work? have you tried to get the result in the console?

Comment: No, the function worked and all, and it replaced the right values, but I have a button that  uses the function to display it onto webpage. I edited my original post with the html code.

Comment: you need another function to wrap the cration of the array, call `fizzBuzz` and assign the value to the output.

Comment: That worked. I need to fix the formatting, but I can do that later.

Answer (score 2):

The return statement is inside the for loop which is why it is returning on the first iteration. check the below code for clarification :

```js
var listOfNumbers = new Array(100);

var i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.length; i++){
        listOfNumbers[i] = i + 1;
    }

function fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers){

for (j = 0; j < listOfNumbers.length; j++){
        if (j % 3 == 0){
            listOfNumbers[j] = "Fizz";
        }
        else if (j % 5 == 0){
            listOfNumbers[j] = "Buzz";
        }
        else{
            listOfNumbers[j] = j;
        } 
       
    }
  return listOfNumbers;
}
console.log(fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `map` approach:

```
function fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers) {
    return listOfNumbers.map(x => {
        if(x % 3 == 0) x = 'Fizz';
        else if(x % 5 == 0) x = 'Buzz';
        return x;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How a programming master do Fizz Buzz in JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fizz Buzz</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">

ol {
    width: 500px;
    line-height: 1.5em;

}
</style>
<body>
<h1>Fizz Buzz</h1>

<ol id="Nums">
</ol>
<script type="text/javascript">
var listOfNumbers = new Array(100);


function fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers){

for (j = 0; j < listOfNumbers.length; j++){
        if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0 && (j + 1) % 5 == 0){
            listOfNumbers[j] = "FizzBuzz";
        }
        else if ((j + 1) % 3 == 0){
            listOfNumbers[j] = "Fizz";
        }
        else if ((j + 1) % 5 == 0){
            listOfNumbers[j] = "Buzz";
        }
        else{
            listOfNumbers[j] = j + 1;
        } 

    }
  return listOfNumbers;
}

function printer(list){
    fizzBuzz(listOfNumbers);
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        var text = document.createTextNode(listOfNumbers[i]);
        item.appendChild(text);
        var list = document.getElementById("Nums");
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
}
printer();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```